# TYPO3 Exception thrown but not shown in FE/BE

Tags: typo3, extbase

How can I show Exception in Debug Mode (Install -> Presets) in FE?

I'm using LTS 7.6.29

My TYPO3 configuration is

```
1 BE/debug
1 FE/debug
* SYS/devIPmask
1 SYS/displayErrors
file SYS/enableDeprecationLog
1 SYS/sqlDebug
0 SYS/systemLogLevel
1 SYS/clearCacheSystem
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

PHP.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
```

Comment: Just to be sure: What do you see in the FE when you are expecting an exception? Error message, page displayed as normal? What is in the Log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use this setting in TypoScript to show Error-Messages in Frontend:

```
config {
        contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
}
```

In the file `LocalConfiguration.php` you've to set following values, it's explained how to set them by using the installtool:

> **SYS**
>   Try, to disable the TYPO3 exception handlers in general:
>
> System > Install > "All Configuration"
>   Filter by (search-field): exceptionhandler
>
> Set empty values:
>
> [SYS][productionExceptionHandler] =
>   [SYS][debugExceptionHandler] =
>   [SYS][errorHandler] =
>
> After debugging set exception handling to the default values:
>
> [SYS][productionExceptionHandler] =
>    TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\ProductionExceptionHandler
>   [SYS][debugExceptionHandler] = TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\DebugExceptionHandler
>   [SYS][errorHandler] = TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\ErrorHandler
>
> After changing the settings you've to delete the file `typo3temp/autoload/autoload_classmap.php` that the changed settings are applied to the system. The file will be new created but with a bit different content.
>   You can delete the file too in installtool by deleting the autoload-information.

Most is explained here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/launch/Administrators/03_Errorhandling/09_OopsAnErrorOccured/Index.html

Comment: My setting was already at config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I tried several times but nothing change for me.  For example, I remove a namespace in Fluid template {namespace n=GeorgRinger\News\ViewHelpers} and I didn't receive error.  My teammate in LTS 6.2 got exception.

Comment: Mhm, did you clear the cache in install-tool?
Even in the docu it's mentioned that sometimes it's not working, if so then I don't know why.

Comment: Yes clear all caches
No exception error with empty [SYS][errorHandler]

Comment: Must be related to a file in `typo3temp` I guess, you still can try to delete files there

Comment: @SteveLeg added detail after search for the right file to delete

Comment: New link for @David answer : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/launch/Administrators/03_Errorhandling/09_OopsAnErrorOccured/Index.html